# Triggers on PostgreSQL Streaming Replication Standby

Tags: postgresql, triggers, database-replication, postgresql-9.4

I have a primary and a standby PostgreSQL 9.4 database. They replicate via streaming replication. I would like to have the standby database notify an application when it is changed (i.e. replays an xlog).

Similar behavior is possible on the primary database by creating triggers on each table that execute pg_notify, then listening to this notify event in an application. However, it seems as though triggers do not run on the standby.

Comment: Triggers are not possible on a replica/standby. The only option I can think of is to set up logical replication (using [pg_logical](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/pglogical/)) and put the triggers on the logical replica. PG 9.4 will require pglogical to be compiled in, I believe.

Comment: Thanks @bma for your comment. I have investigated pg_logical (and logical replication in Postgres 10). It would indeed solve my problem and may be the solution I go with.

The other option I considered is polling the last received xlog location for changes. The problem with this solution is that I do not believe it is possible to determine which table(s) changed.

Comment: You might be able to use [pg_xlogdump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/pgxlogdump.html), or in PG10 pg_waldump

Comment: you could set up triggers to insert into another table with columns `table_name` & `last_updated` whenever a logged table has rows inserted, deleted or updated and read from that table to find out which tables have been updated, but the triggers would be in primary, only reading this metadata table would happen on the replica